# Where did the money for continuing the Jaeger program come from?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the beginning of the movie, the funding for the Jaeger program is being cancelled, because they aren't good enough. Pentecost however, says he doesn't need his financiers, he's going to go on anyway.

So where does he get the money? From his own purse? Is he really that rich?

I know, usually finances don't really play that great a role in this kind of movie. But in this scene, they make it very clear that withdrawing all the funding will effectively bring the program to a halt, and Pentecost's reaction of "no it won't" made me wonder.

Comment: 300ft aliens beating giant robots to death and you're worried about whether they're using double-entry bookkeeping?

Comment: Ah... _that_'s how they did it.

Comment: Kickstarter, clearly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Pacific Rim Wikia [suggests](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Stacker_Pentecost) that the program's application for renewed funding was rejected, but that they still have eight months on the clock. The events of the movie took place within that time period.

> By 2025, the unprecedented number of attacks from the Kaiju in 2024 diminished the forces of the Jaeger Program. **With no hope in the program, the United Nations begin to shut down all but one of the Shatterdomes and retire PPDC personnel.** Stacker pleads with the United Nations representatives for more time to plan a final assault against the breach with everything they have. They deny his request and give him eight months of funding to finish the rest of his service in Hong Kong. **Frustrated, Stacker decides to proceed with his plan without the UN's help** and heads for the Anti-Kaiju Wall to find Raleigh, who disappeared four years earlier after his dismissal from the Jaeger Program following Knifehead's defeat.[5][4]

And on [another page](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Shatterdome):

> When twenty six Jaegers were destroyed, seven Shatterdomes were closed and funding was reallocated to the construction of the Anti-Kaiju Wall.[1] However, **PPDC Marshall Stacker Pentecost was given eight months of funding in order to keep the Hong Kong Shatterdome operational**.

Comment: However, I haven't personally seen the movie so I could be missing a nuance or fact.

Comment: That's OK; they didn't make it very clear in the movie anyway that funding would continue for 8 months.

Comment: "they didn't make it very clear in the movie anyway that funding would continue for 8 months." sure, if you ignore the bit where they explicitly tell pentecost "we're prepared to fund you for another eight months"

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous answer which explains the funding didn't immediately end Stacker Pentecost also strikes a deal with Hannibal Chau (that's how he knew to send Newt to him).

Hannibal uses money he makes on the black market to fund the Shatterdome in exchange for exclusive rights to Kaiju remains.

This business deal is beneficial to both sides, Stacker gets his money and Hannibal gets his remains. Remember if Jaegers aren't killing Kaiju then his supply dries up!

From the Pacific Rim [wiki](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Hannibal_Chau)

> He remains able to sell or salvage Kaiju parts because of the sole
>   supplier contract he has with Stacker Pentecost. The arrangement which
>   provides the Marshall with the necessary funding for the war effort
>   and Kaiju parts which have military value.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer to the OP; "Where did the money for continuing the Jaeger program come from?" As you say it came from black market kickbacks.